# progress bar and timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, progress-bar

Having trouble with my c# windows form. The expectation is when I load form2 the timer should start and increase the progress bar. The bar itself is just a dummy bar as it is not actually doing much. It will open a pop up window when it is completed. At the moment i'm just trying to get it to move.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void f2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 10;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    }

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (progressBar1.Value != 10)
        {
            progressBar1.Value++;
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it would be sensible to start a timer AFTER it is setup....!

Comment: "The expectation is when I load form2 the timer should start and increase the progress bar." when I try your code this expectation is confirmed to 100%. What is the actual problem that you have?

Comment: You forgot to tell what's wrong... at first glance the code looks fine, what happens when you run it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Like I said the problem is that the progress bar doesn't move. If you run the code the bar is still empty.

Comment: is it possible that you have 2 progress bars overlapping? or simply one is somewhere behind a control and the other (that you actually see) is called `progressBar2` or something ?

Comment: "If you run the code the bar is still empty." No that is not entirely true. If **I** run the code the bar is full. So the code doesn't seem to be the problem here

Comment: There's only progressBar1 in the solutions explorer.

Comment: How did you create f2_Load btw? Double clicking on designer should've created Form2_Load. So either you've explicitly renamed it to f2_Load, or you just created f2_Load but never hooking the event handler for Form2_Load

Comment: did set a breakpoint in the Load event and see with the Debugger whether it stops?

Comment: Are you sure you've hooked the loaded event to the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try to register manually the Load event:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Load += f2_Load;
}
```

Comment: Thank you yours and Yvette Colomb reply fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Double clicking on the form in the designer should give you the `Load` event.

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {...}
```

Notice **Form2** in `Form2_Load`.

Else, manually create the load event and hook it up.

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Load += f2_Load;
}
public void f2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{...}
```